# Memory profiling a Rust binary with XCode 13.2.1

Tags: xcode, rust, xcode13, memory-profiling

With an earlier version of Xcode, I was able to profile my Rust binaries' allocations following these instructions.  It worked beautifully.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2434/_index.html

Now, I'm using version 13.2.1, and Xcode shows me empty windows.

I set up the profiling session like this:
[image]

Then, I click the run button.  The Debugging Session panel lights up for a second or two, then my process exits and I'm left looking at the following.  I don't see allocations profile information or a button to click to show it to me.

[image]

I tried using Release and Debug binaries, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the old "Instruments."  [image]

Just skip the tools in Xcode.